# Write a networking simulator like Packet tracer with Netbean, how should I approach?

Tags: java, netbeans, ip, inet

I have a project which developing a java program - packet tracer alike. I have managed to get the most of GUI done with movable PCs, popup, etc.. but i'm totally clueless about the best way to give PCs IPs, Subneting and further development like Ping, tracert etc....

Can anyone enlighten me with any idea?

Picture 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wq9bowrwwmib6kx/1.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eas558lr80evxeg/2.png

Comment: Real ips or user created?

Comment: just IP from JTextfield input by user, just like packet tracer developed by Cisco

Answer (score 0):

Simple object oriented programming. First make object classes for what you need. store these objects in an arrey after you create them. Its kind of like your own little database  for your program. When they need to be used run a for loop to check for the object you need. You can save these list so the user can reopen your program and continue working from where they left off.